# dask.array.compute() fails with RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error

Tags: netcdf4

I set up a Dask cluster of 100 cores across 5 nodes through PBS. Then I read in about 1000 MODIS (hdf5) tiles using Xarray's open_mfdataset. After concatenating the arrays to have all the timesteps (92 per tile) together, I try to compute the Euclidean distance of one data point, q, from all the other points, and use argtopk to get the 500 smallest ones. When I call compute on this array of 500 results, I get: RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error

Tried with different cluster sizes, and reading files from both NFS and Lustre

```py
# create random sketch vectors with elements either + or - one
sketch_len = 10
rv = np.random.randint(2, size=(92,sketch_len))
rv = rv + (rv - 1)
rv_da = xr.DataArray(rv, dims=['time','rv'])

conus_tile_sketches = []
for ct in conus_tiles:
  tile_ts=xr.open_mfdataset(tiles,concat_dim='time',mask_and_scale=False,
combine='nested',parallel=True)['500m 16 days NDVI']
  tile_ts = tile_ts.transpose('y','x','time')
  tile_ts = tile_ts.chunk((100,100,92))
  tile_sketch = tile_ts.dot(rv_da)
  tile_sketch = client.persist(tile_sketch)
  conus_tile_sketches.append(tile_sketch)

flat_sketches = da.concatenate(conus_tile_sketches,axis=1)
flat_sketches = client.persist(flat_sketches)

q = flat_sketches[:,30123456]
q=q.reshape(10,1)
dist = da.linalg.norm(flat_sketches - q, axis = 0)
dist = client.persist(dist)
closest_idx = dist.argtopk(-501)
closest_idx=closest_idx.compute()


should return value of closest_idx array. Instead I get the following stack trace. 

Note, my dist dask array is large: 

>>> dist
dask.array<pow, shape=(63360000,), dtype=float64, chunksize=(19200,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 175, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 446, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 2520, in get
    results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1820, in gather
    asynchronous=asynchronous,
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 754, in sync
    self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 337, in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 321, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1676, in _gather
    raise exception.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 108, in getter
    c = np.asarray(c)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 452, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 610, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 516, in __array__
    return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py", line 42, in __getitem__
    return np.asarray(self.array[key], dtype=self.dtype)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 516, in __array__
    return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 70, in __getitem__
    self._getitem)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 784, in explicit_indexing_adapter
    result = raw_indexing_method(raw_key.tuple)
  File "/home7/jcbecker/.conda/envs/geo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 81, in _getitem
    array = getitem(original_array, key)
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 4351, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 5296, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._get
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1857, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using larger chunksize. In tile reading loop, replace:

```
tile_ts = tile_ts.chunk((100,100,92))
```

with

```
tile_ts = tile_ts.chunk((1200,1200,92))
```